# git2go fetch remote tags

Tags: git, go, libgit2

Im trying to fetch the tags from a remote with git2go(https://github.com/libgit2/git2go).
When i'm cloning the repository I can list all the tags with the following code:

```
iter, err := repository.NewReferenceIterator()

ref, err := iter.Next()
for err == nil {
    if ref.IsTag() {
        fmt.Println(ref.Name())
    }

    ref, err = iter.Next()
}
```

But when I fetch the code from the remote it does not update the tags.
Im fetching new code from the repository with:

```
remote, err := p.repository.LoadRemote("origin")
remote.Fetch([]string{}, nil, "")
```

This is my config:

```
[core]
    bare = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = file:///home/testrepo

    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I've added([Can I specify in .git/config to fetch multiple refspecs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507264/can-i-specify-in-git-config-to-fetch-multiple-refspecs?answertab=votes#tab-top)):

```
fetch = refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

But that does not do anything.

I also added the tags in the refspec but that gave the error: ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' doesn't match the destination

Answer (score 2):

The doc of the [Remote.Fetch()](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go/blob/3b7cc1e97e62cf240f93a08983a0dc18bd31c54c/remote.go#L526) method mentions:

> use an empty list to use the refspecs from the configuration.

The **[default refspec](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#CRTB)** [does not import tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097913/6309).
(Even with regular git, [you would need a `git fetch --tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309)).
By default:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You can either:

- use a non-empty list of refspecs in the `Fetch()` method,

  ```
  []string{"+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*", "refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"}
  ```
- or it is possible to [add multiple refspec to a fetch config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15507264/6309) though, using (with git2go) the [`(o *Remote) FetchRefspecs() ([]string, error)` method](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go/blob/3b7cc1e97e62cf240f93a08983a0dc18bd31c54c/remote.go#L429).

---

[gyre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569763/gyre) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466784/git2go-fetch-remote-tags/26467296#comment41777416_26467296) having [this code](https://gist.github.com/milosgajdos83/969e4bf59f0c0a9e45b4) working up to a point:

> up to the point where I need to PEEL the tag: Peel is where `git2go` somehow returns errors that it can't peel the reference into tag.

Comment: thanks for your help so far. I Read the links you passed but can't seem to set the right refspec:
And what should i put in here? I use remote.Fetch([]string{"refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"}, nil, "") but this gives me an error: 'refs/remotes/origin/master' doesn't match the destination.

Comment: @user1979738 `"+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*", "refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Still getting the error: ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' doesn't match the destination. I've added my cloned repo config, but it does look the same as these refspecs..

Comment: @user1979738 could you try, just to check, `"+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*", "refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*"`? Also that might mean the remote 'origin' isn't properly defined.

Comment: It still gives me the same: 'refs/remotes/origin/master' doesn't match the destination.

Comment: @user1979738 could you try (again just for testing) `"refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"`

Comment: That does not update the tag list, but it does not give me an error

Comment: That sounds like a bug in libgit2, that error message would come from some part of the fetch code trying to use a refspec against a reference that should not be used against it.

Comment: Interestingly enough I'm working on something very similar and only just found this question on SO. The following code works for me up to the point where I need to PEEL the tag: https://gist.github.com/milosgajdos83/969e4bf59f0c0a9e45b4. Peel is where git2go somehow returns errors that it can't peel the reference into tag.