# How to git fetch by branch creator from stash

Tags: git, git-stash

when I use the command:

**git fetch**

I am getting all the branch created on the remote which are not on my local machine.

*But I only want to fetch the remote branches that I created myself.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the **[refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)** associated to an upstream repo is

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/schacon/simplegit-progit
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

That is why you are getting many remote tracking branches.

You can modify/add new refspecs for the fetch, as seen in "[Can I specify in .git/config to fetch multiple refspecs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508750/6309)".

If you have a naming convention which allows you to determine what are the branches you have created, you can use a pattern to fetch only those.

But you cannot fetch based on the "creator" of a branch, since Git doesn't record who created a branch.

Comment: Thanks, and you are right using a naming convention will solve that. I will use names  like this: author/[old-branch-name]