# git pull command output message meaning into which branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull, git-remote

Say there is a remote branch `br1` checkout on the remote repo, and the `master` branch on a local repo.

- Command 1: If I do a "`git pull origin br1:br1`" it pulls remote `br1` into local `br1`, and shows: 

  `9188a5d..97d4825  br1        -> br1
  9188a5d..97d4825  br1        -> origin/br1`
- command 2: If I do just a "`git pull`", it will pull remote `br1` into local `master`, but it shows only the following:

  `9188a5d..97d4825  br1        -> origin/br1`

I'm expecting it also shows something like "`br1 -> master`". Why it does not show that?

Does "`br1 -> br1`" mean pulling remote `br1` into local `br1`?

What does that "`br1 -> origin/br1`" mean?

**Update**: With help from VonC, I figured out the following:

- `git pull` updates all the tracking branches. `br1 -> origin/br1` means `br1` on the remote is pulled into local tracking branch `origin/br1`.
- `git pull origin br1:br1` pulls remote `br1` into local `br1` and into `origin/br1`. Then the messages after that mean the same change set is also pulled into the current checked-out branch (the message is `Updating ...`, it does not show `br1 -> master`):

  `$ git pull origin br1:br1
     beb48a4..b344dd1  br1        -> br1
     beb48a4..b344dd1  br1        -> origin/br1
  Updating cca5a9b..b344dd1
  Fast-forward
   file2 | 0
   file3 | 0
   4 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)`
- Previously I thought `git pull` pulls into the local master. That is not the case. It is that `git pull origin br1:br1` does it.

**Update 2**: With explanations by torek, the specific problem is that the command `git pull origin br1:br1` pulls remote `br1` into `FETCH_HEAD` after a sequence of other actions and subsequently merges the `FETCH_HEAD` onto the current branch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Warning: long.  TL;DR version: you are looking at `git fetch` output and `git fetch` is not affecting your `master` at all, it's the `git merge` part of your `git pull` that affects your `master`.  However, your `git fetch` is updating a remote-tracking branch `origin/br1` and in one case updating or even creating a local branch `br1`.

#### `git pull` is a convenience script

Always remember that `git pull` is just a convenience script that runs two other git commands for you: first, `git pull` passes your arguments on to `git fetch`.  Once that finishes, `git pull` runs `git merge` (or, if instructed, `git rebase`), but all of the quoted action in your original question is occurring purely in `git fetch`.  (A bit in the "update" section is from `git merge`, which I'll get to later.)

If you do not provide a *remote* argument to `git pull`, the `pull` script extracts one from your current branch's configuration.  In this case, the one it extracts is clearly `origin`.  So If you run `git pull` without specifying `origin`, you are, in effect, running `git pull origin`.

If you do not provide a *refspec* argument to `git pull`, the `pull` script extracts a very simple one from your current branch's configuration—in this case, whatever you see from `git config --get branch.master.merge`, which apparently is `br1`.  So this means that if you run `git pull origin`, you are in effect running `git pull origin br1`.<sup>1</sup>

Again, all of this is then just passed on to `git fetch`, so whether you run `git pull`, `git pull origin`, or `git pull origin br1`, all of those just wind up invoking:

```
git fetch origin br1
```

(which you can also do manually, and you'll see the above).

We'll get to `git fetch origin br1:br1` later, below.

#### Background on possible misconceptions

Let's take a brief look at your setup statement again:

> Say there is a remote branch `br1` checkout on the remote repo, and the `master` branch on a local repo.

What branch, if any, is currently *checked-out* on the remote is *mostly* irrelevant for `fetch`.  The first (or first-enough) thing `fetch` does is to connect to the remote and ask it for a list of all references and their corresponding SHA-1s (you can see what `git fetch` can see by running `git ls-remote`).  The remote's `HEAD` *is* included in that list, and this allows you to direct your `fetch` to use it, but if you don't, your `fetch` just ignores it (the remote's `HEAD` is mostly only used for controlling the default initial branch on an initial `git clone`).

The current branch in your *local* repo *is* important, though, for two reasons:

- if you don't supply extra arguments to `git pull`, it finds them based on your current branch; and
- after the `fetch` succeeds, `git pull` runs either `git merge` or `git rebase`, which uses your current branch.

Again, your current branch is `master` so `pull` will use `branch.master.remote` and `branch.master.merge` as the default *remote* and *refspec* arguments.<sup>2</sup>  This is how we can deduce, from the original output, that these are `origin` and `br1` respectively.

#### On `git fetch`

Returning to `git fetch`, what it does is to confer with the remote git server a bit to find out what references (branches and tags, mostly) are available and what their corresponding SHA-1 values are.  Once it has that information, it then looks at which references you've asked it to bring over.  If you listed a specific reference like `br1`, that's the one reference it will bring over.

Along with each reference, of course, it has to bring any new objects (the commit itself, and its associated trees and files, plus any parent commits and their trees-and-files as needed) so that you get all the history from that particular point backwards.  Whatever history you already have, of course, it can skip.<sup>3</sup>

As [VonC already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28337616/1256452), git's behavior on `git fetch remote refspec` has changed in git 1.8.4 and later.  It used to be the case that if you ran `git fetch remote refspec`, your refspec *overrode* the rules in your git configuration entry for that remote, but now it simply *selects from them*.  By default, the rule-set for the remote named `origin` is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, so your `br1` refspec selects an item from this rule-set.

---

Let's pause to see what happens if you run `git fetch` with only *three* arguments, like this:

```
$ git fetch origin
```

Here you are instructing your local git to connect to the remote, find out what it has, and bring over *all* branches.  The way (and reason) it does that is just as outlined above: it connects, gets a list, and then consults the output of `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`.<sup>4</sup>  This is a list of "refspecs", one per `git config --get-all` line.

Since the standard line (one single line) for `remote.origin.fetch` is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, your local git will take every reference-name that matches `refs/heads/*`.  That is, it will take all branches on `origin`, because branches are simply "references whose names start with `refs/heads/`".  What it *does* with those branches is determined by the right-hand side of this refspec: it replaces `refs/heads/` with `refs/remotes/origin/`.

The result is a "remote-tracking branch".  If the remote has a branch `master`, your local git translates this to `origin/master`.  If the remote has a `br1`, your local git translates that to `origin/br1`.  For each branch on the remote, you get a (local) remote-tracking branch whose name starts with `origin/`.<sup>5</sup>

---

Returning to our case of `git fetch origin br1`, we can now see what happens: our local git brings over `br1`, which turns out to be a branch so that its full name is `refs/heads/br1`.  Because of that, it matches the standard `remote.origin.fetch` line and `refs/heads/br1` is translated to `refs/remotes/origin/br1`, which causes git to print out `origin/br1`:

> ```
> 9188a5d..97d4825  br1        -> origin/br1
> ```

The name `br1` on the left is the short name of the reference on the remote, and the name `origin/br1` on the right is the short name of the reference that `git fetch` has updated.

In the past you would instead see something like this—and you still may see it:

```
* branch            name       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

This indicates that `git fetch` found a branch named `name` (i.e., a reference of the form `refs/heads/name`) on the remote and brought it over to your local repo and put it in `FETCH_HEAD`.  What is `FETCH_HEAD`?  It's a special file that exists pretty much just for the `git pull` script.  (It works a lot like a reference, but it has a special format and may contains multiple SHA-1s.)

---

Now we're (finally) ready to tackle the `br1:br1` case.  Here, you're telling your local `git fetch` to bring over reference `br1`.  It does the usual—call up the remote, discover that `br1` is really `refs/heads/br1`, and bring over the reference and any needed objects—but this time, in addition to consulting the `remote.origin.fetch` line, it writes the new SHA-1 into the reference *you* specified.

In this case, you specified `br1` with no qualifications: not `refs/heads/br1`, not `refs/remotes/origin/br1`, just `br1`.  In this case, git sees that it's a `refs/heads/` reference on the remote, meaning it's a branch; so git adds `refs/heads/` on your end as well, and creates or updates your own `refs/heads/br1`.

In other words, this creates or updates your *local* branch `br1`.

In addition, git still applies the `remote.origin.fetch` line, which is still `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, so it still updates your remote-tracking branch `origin/br1` (full name `refs/remotes/origin/br1`).  **That's why you got the output you got from Command 1.**

#### On `git merge`

What about `FETCH_HEAD`?  Well, that's where the rest of `git pull` comes back in: after doing the `git fetch` step, the `pull` script runs either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  What it merges (or rebases-on-to) is *whatever `git fetch` left behind in the `FETCH_HEAD` file* (with some special casing and other caveats that I won't go into here).

When your current branch is `master` but you instruct `git pull` to pull `origin br1`, **it's the `git merge` step that brings `master` up to date with `br1`.**  More precisely, the merge gets you up to date with your copy of `origin/br1` as of the time the `git fetch` finished—it's possible that just after your `git fetch` finished, someone else did a `git push` that updated `br1` on your remote.

The merge is a "fast-forward" merge if possible, but again I won't go into any more details on that here.  I'll just note that it was possible, so it was done; that's the `Fast-forward` line in the update.

In any case, the merge brought in to your current branch (`master`) the changes since the merge-base of your current branch and your target commit (the raw SHA-1 that `git fetch` left in the `FETCH_HEAD` file, which is also the new SHA-1 of `origin/br1`, and in one case, the new SHA-1 of new-or-updated local branch `br1`).

In pre-1.8.4 versions of git, the `origin/br1` remote-tracking branch is not updated.  Everything still works out of the `FETCH_HEAD` file though, and it is, if anything, even *more* confusing than in newer gits, where we can say that you're now up to date with `origin/br1` without having to be very exacting and picky about "`br1` as it was on the remote at the time you ran `git fetch`".

#### What's that plus sign?

Sharp-eyed readers will have noted the `+` in `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.  This `+` symbol means "forced update".  Normally, when updating a branch reference—any reference starting with `refs/heads/`—git won't *allow* the update unless it's a "fast-forward" label update.  Setting the force flag in a refspec allows that particular update.  Using `--force` on the command line also allows that update, and all other reference updates as well.  In other words, the plus sign is simply a more-targeted (single refspec) version of `--force`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is an overstatement: sometimes it uses a three-argument `git fetch`.

<sup>2</sup>Always true for the *remote* bit but the *refspec* bit may be empty, with the `pull` script figuring out which refspec to apply later, after `git fetch` finishes.

<sup>3</sup>By default, the `fetch` operation will also bring over any tag-name references that match any commit-IDs that it brings over.  If you run `git fetch` yourself, you can change the way `fetch` handles these, but if you just let `git pull` run `git fetch` you will get this default behavior.  Note that it's your local git that makes these decisions: the remote git simply displays everything to your local git, and then your git decides whether to add tags to your repository.

<sup>4</sup>Technically `git fetch` just invokes the C code that does this, rather than actually running `git config --get-all`.  In any case, if there are multiple configuration entries for `remote.origin.fetch`, `git fetch origin` really does apply all of them.  The way it does this is a bit complicated though, and I will skip the gory details here.

<sup>5</sup>Remote-tracking branches are really just references whose name starts with `refs/remotes/`, just as local branches are references whose name starts with `refs/heads/`.  This is a general thing in git: your tags are references whose name starts with `refs/tags`.  The `git stash` script uses a single special reference, `refs/stash`.  Git's "notes" are stored under `refs/notes/`, and you can invent your own references: just pick a different starting string, and hope that nobody else picks the same one in the future for a new git feature. :-)

Comment: I thought about explaining git fetch and the refspec (that I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28008700/6309), ... but I told to myself "meh, torek will take care of it". I was right. +1

Comment: One question though: `branch.master.merge` is `refs/heads/master` not `br1`. I guess `git pull` not showing `master -> origin/master` is because lack of change on the remote master. So guess `git pull` does a three parameter fetch `git fetch origin` that goes over all remote branches. But that does not change the validity of your answers.

Comment: Aha, yes, it appears that the `pull` script has gotten more complicated again, and now sometimes uses the three-argument form of `get fetch`.  To see the actual script, look at `git-pull` in the directory found via `git --exec-path`.

Answer (score 1):

Any line with `origin/xxxx` means the `git fetch` part of a [`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) (which is [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) + [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)) has updated a [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6309).
that is so since [git 1.8.4 (before it only updated `FETCH_HEAD`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20967347/6309).

> If I do just a "git pull", it will pull remote br1 into local master

That would depend on `git config branch.b1.merge`, which instruct the git merge part of the `git pull` *where* to merge.
By doing a `git pull b1:b1`, you are overriding that config and instructing the merge to take place in the local `b1` branch.

See also the result of [`git branch -avvv`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) to see what local branch is tracking what remote branch.

> I'm expecting it also shows something like "br1 -> master". Why it does not show that?

Maybe `master` was already at `97d4825`.

Comment: Ah, A different behaviour since 1.8.4! No wonder I did not see this before. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know where are all your branches at? I know I can check them out one by one and look at the log.

Comment: @minghua that is what `git branch -avvv` is for.

Comment: Yes I saw that after posting my comment. Thanks!