# How can I fetch notes from a remote git repository with TortoiseGit?

Tags: tortoisegit, git-notes

A typical use of notes is to supplement a commit message without changing the commit itself. Notes can be shown by git log along with the original commit message ([Git-notes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)). With [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)  I can create a note by **Edit notes** context menu, and then push this note to a remote repository by the **Sync** -> **Push notes** command. The notes then appear in the remote repository as expected.

On the other side I didn't find any possibility to **fetch** notes, neither with **clone**, nor with **fetch** or **pull** command.

What is the usual way to make sure *git notes* appear in every cloned repository?

**Edit:** I'm using TortoiseGit 2.7.0.0 and Git 2.19.2.windows.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Just use `refs/notes/commits` as branch name (local/remote)

Comment: @MrTux How can I do that with TGit? I don't see any "notes" node under "refs" in "Browse References" dialog.

Comment: Enter it manually.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally lost, could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Notes are implemented in Git as a "normal" branch.

Therefore, you can easily fetch, pull and push it using `refs/notes/commits`. Just enter `refs/notes/commits` as local and remote branch in the fetch/pull/push dialog.

cf. https://web.archive.org/web/20180121193320/http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/08/25/notes.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269026/3906760.

Comment: Thank you, @mrtux. I found that before, but my question was about TortoiseGit (I tweaked the title of my question). I assume it would be an easy solution for this tool. Because it can edit, show and push notes, I suppose it can pull them, too.

Comment: Indeed I could not find any possibility in TortoiseGit to do this, because at all places I just found dropdown lists without permission to enter free text. But there is the alternative to add the line `fetch = +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*` to the remote's section of the `.git/config` file. From this time on, notes are fetched automatically.

Comment: To state it more precisely, it must be added to the `[remote "<my-remote>"]` section. I.e. you have more than one `fetch` line then. This is apparently perfectly normal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508750/443836.