# How can I git pull to only fetch the current branch?

Tags: git

After looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052005/how-can-you-git-pull-only-the-current-branch) I couldn't find any answers that worked, aside from perhaps overriding the bash command.

I would like `git pull` to only fetch branches that I have a local branch for, if not just the current one. I prefer not to manually `git fetch origin develop` then `git rebase origin/develop`

---

I don't want these random remote braches polluting my `git lg` command:

```
# .gitconfig
[alias]
    lg = log --all --decorate --branches --oneline --graph --color --date=short
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instruct `pull` to fetch only your local branch, by passing the arguments to `pull`, for example:

```
git pull origin develop
# or if you always track a branch of the same name, perhaps an alias like:
[alias]
    p = !git pull origin $(git branch --show-current)
```

That way you will only fetch and merge (or rebase) the branch you specify.

As for "all" of your local branches, I don't think you can change the behavior of `git pull` to fetch all of, *and only*, your local branches in a single command. You could create an alias to loop through each local branch name and fetch that branch, perhaps like this (in bash):

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/ | xargs git fetch origin
```

**That being said**, since the reason you wish to do this is to avoid printing out all the remotes in your `lg` alias, **you could try simply removing the `--all` option from your alias**, which says to include all local and remote branches. The `--branches` option which you also already have (which is currently redundant), says to include all of your local branches. After removing `--all`, you should be able to simply `git fetch` (or let `pull` fetch all branches), and your `lg` alias will still work (similarly) to what you've been doing. A caveat here is that this will no longer also show the corresponding remote versions of your local branches, so that may not be exactly what you want.

Comment: Is there an easy way to subsequently perform a merge or rebase with the current checked out branch? This would perform a `pull` substitute which is what I'm ultimately looking for

Comment: @neaumusic You could make an alias that fetches just your current branch and then rebases onto (or merges in) the remote counterpart. Something like: `git fetch origin $(git branch --show-current) && git rebase @{u}`

Comment: @neaumusic it just occurred to me that my last comment can be simplified to use pull, which is actually closer to what you asked. ;) I updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Git already only pulls the current branch. If you have branch set up as a tracking branch, you do not need to specify the remote branch. git branch --set-upstream localbranch reponame/remotebranch will set up the tracking relationship. You then issue git pull [--rebase] and only that branch will be updated.

Comment: ... No, git pull updates all the remote references, and fetches all the commits associated with those, not just for the single branch as you write.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. `git pull` does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. It's the `git fetch` part, with no arguments, that OP is trying to avoid.